# Compatibility if changing C++ class member pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, linker, compatibility

According to [KDE-Techbase](http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++#The_Do.27s_and_Don.27ts) it is not allowed to change a class members type.
But changing the type of an pointer is binary compatible, isn't it?
For example in "MyClass.DLL":

```
class A
{
    int * m;
};
```

i changed this to:

```
class A
{
    B * m;
};
```

Is this valid or will it break compatibility across DLLs?
I think so, because pointers are always stored in 32/64 bit.

Comment: It may not break the API, but to do so is surely not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The standard makes no such guarantee, but *if you assume a specific platform* (e.g. Windows) you know more about that implementation:  indeed, all pointers (non- pointer-to-member) are the same size and alignment for structure layout.

You can verify this for a particular case by looking at the size of the object and the [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) various data members.  Keep the old definition under a new name, and add `static_assert` (or Boost's if you have older compiler) to **validate the assumptions**.  That way you won't get bit by any funny business due to automatic error checking in debug builds, or issues you did not know about.